Magento2 | Get ratings for each review
I am trying to take product reviews programmatically, filter them by product and pull out the rating stars.
I can get the text of the reviews (getDetail()) without any problems and in fact I see all the review texts including the creation dates. What I can't see is the rating score of the review. Whenever I try to print out getRatingVotes the value always returns 0. As if the ratings are not saved but they are actually there. This is my code:
<?php
    $product_id = $_product->getId();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $rating = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Review\Model\Rating');
    $review = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Review\Model\Review');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
    $_ratingSummary = $rating->getEntitySummary($product_id);
    $ratingCollection = $review->getResourceCollection()
                        ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                        ->addEntityFilter('product', $product_id)
                        ->setDateOrder()
                        ->addRateVotes();
    $review_count = count($ratingCollection); // How many review in that specific product
    
    
    
    
    
    foreach($ratingCollection->getItems() as $ratingItem){
            echo $ratingItem->getDetail().' '.'<br/>';
            if(count($ratingItem->getRatingVotes()) > 0){
                foreach($ratingItem->getRatingVotes() as $_vote){
                    echo $_vote->getPercent().'<br/>';
                }
            }
    }
?>

How come I can't see the ratings score for the review?

\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product

    
    $result = $items = $starData = [];      
    $idArray = [2,5]; // product id
    $reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value',array("in" => $idArray))
        ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
        ->addRateVotes();
    $reviewsCollection->getSelect();

    foreach ($reviewsCollection->getItems() as $review) {

        foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote ) {
            $rating = [];
            $percent = $_vote->getPercent();
            $star = ($percent/20);
            $productId = $_vote->getEntityPkValue();
            
            $productModel = $this->_product->create();
            $product = $productModel->load($productId);             
            $countReview = $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getTotalReviews($productId,false);
            $review_id = $_vote->getReviewId();
            
            $rating['review_id'] = $review_id;
            $rating['product_id'] = $productId;     
            $rating['percent']   = $percent;
            $rating['star']      = $star;
            $rating['nickname']  = $review->getNickname();                  
            $items[] = $rating;
            $starData[$star][] = $rating;
        }
        
    }
    
    if(count($items) > 0)   {           
        $result['all'] = $items;
        $result['star'] = $starData;            
        
        if(isset($starData[1]))
            $result ['count'][1] = count($starData[1]);
        else
            $result ['count'][1] = 0;
            
        if(isset($starData[2]))
            $result ['count'][2] = count($starData[2]);
        else
            $result ['count'][2] = 0;
            
        if(isset($starData[3]))
            $result ['count'][3] = count($starData[3]);
        else
            $result ['count'][3] = 0;
            
        if(isset($starData[4]))
            $result ['count'][4] = count($starData[4]);
        else
            $result ['count'][4] = 0;
        
        if(isset($starData[5]))
            $result ['count'][5] = count($starData[5]);
        else
            $result ['count'][5] = 0;
        
        $sum = $startSum = 0;
        
        foreach($result['count'] as $number => $count) {
            $sum += $number * $count;
            $startSum +=  $count;   
        }
        
        $avg =  $sum/$startSum;
        
        $result ['count']['all'] = count($result['all']);
        $result ['count']['avg'] = round($avg,1);
    }
    
    return $result; 

